# Python - .apply() function returning entire column of rows in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First time posting; apologies for formatting errors.  I have a data set that contains age ranges in separate columns, and I'm trying to create a new column based on a string evaluation of the AGE_OPERATOR_TXT column:

I've tried using .apply() functions, lambda, for loops with iterrows(), etc... but either I can't get anything to return, or the function returns a series with ALL of the rows:

```
def multum_age_ops(s):
    if s == "<":
        return data['AGE_LOW_NBR'] + " + " + data['AGE_UNIT_DISP']
else:
    return 0

data['age_op_test'] = data['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT'].apply(multum_age_ops)
```

I would expect that the column returned would actually look something like:

```
age_ops_test
0 0
1 18 + years
2 1 + months
3 4 + months
4 4 + months
```

What I'm getting is:

```
age_ops_test
0                                                        0
1        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
2        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
3        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
4        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
5        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
6        0        18\n1        18\n2         1\n3      ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because *you are returning a series*: `return data['AGE_LOW_NBR'] + " + " + data['AGE_UNIT_DISP']` that's a series...

Comment: You should be doing this, if you really want to do it with apply, by applying across the whole dataframe with `axis=1`. Perhaps consider just concatenating across by element using the series syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  Again, first question, so I should have mentioned that I did try ```data['age_op_test'] = data['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT'].apply(multum_age_ops, axis=1)``` but it returns an "unexpected argument" error.

Comment: My final workaround (not very Pythonic) was to create the first column based on sinanggul's suggestion, then create a second that evaluates and instead of returning 0 in the ```else``` clause, returns the first column. Then a third that evaluates as above and returns the second column in the ```else``` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [ifly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2741091/ifly6)'s comment, the key is to use `apply` on the entire dataframe over `axis=1` so that the function/lambda gets applied to each row.  In your case, that would look like this:

```
data['age_op_test'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['AGE_LOW_NBR'] + " + " + row['AGE_UNIT_DISP'] if row['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT'] == "<" else "0", axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - now I need to extend it to include two more "elif" clauses.  Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.where` ([doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)):

```
data['age_op_test'] = np.where(data['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT'] == "<", data['AGE_LOW_NBR'] + " + " + data['AGE_UNIT_DISP'],0)
```

What `np.where` does in this case is returns "0" if `data['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT'] == "<"` is `False`. If `True`, it returns `data['AGE_LOW_NBR'] + " + " + data['AGE_UNIT_DISP']`.

Comment: There's no `pd` prefix before `np`

Comment: You are correct @ifly6, thank you. Answer was edited to reflect change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do something like this :

```py
df.loc[df['AGE_OPERATOR_TXT']=='<', "age_op_test"] = df["AGE_LOW_NBR"].astype(str).str.cat(df["AGE_UNIT_DISP"].astype(str), sep=" + ")
```